# multi language website by codeigniter with language in link

Tags: php, codeigniter, permalinks, multilingual

I managed to make a multi language website on codeigniter so far, it took me a while and a lot of research to find it out so I'll post details here too in case some one is looking to make the same thing and also you can help me with my problem..
The problem is I want to have my website links be like this :

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/ru
http://www.example.com/it ...etc
```

I used this tutorial to do it:
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/multi-language-codeigniter/

I have the language switcher in the views this way

```
<form method="POST" action="<?= base_url() ?>LanguageSwitcher/switchlang">
 <input type="hidden" name="uri" value="<?= uri_string(); ?>" />
   <select name="language" onchange="this.form.submit()">
     <option>Select language</option>  
     <option value="en">English</option>
     <option value="ru">Russian</option>
     <option value="it">Italian</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

so basically I store the language selection in session so I can use it later for "get where" for fetching from the database

and here is my routes file

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/index/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

and here is my config file, I tried to do this

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['site_lang'])) {
  if ($_SESSION['site_lang'] == "en") {
      $base_url = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
  }else{
      $base_url = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/'.$_SESSION['site_lang'].'/';
  }
}else{
  $base_url = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
}
   $config['base_url'] = $base_url;
```

but it didn't work and even if it worked, the uri wont even recognize what the "/ru" part is in the link
the main question is, is there even a way to do what I'm trying to do in codeigniter without using models or making different lang methods for each lang in controllers?

is there a way I could just have it look like this "example.com/ru" for each language so it would be good for search engines?